# C++ Static Array Initialization - Memory Issue

Tags: c++

I have a header file which contains a member variable declaration of a static char array:

```
class ABC 
{ 
public:
static char newArray[4];
// other variables / functions
private:
void setArray(int i, char * ptr);
}
```

In the CPP file, I have the array initialized to NULL:

```
char ABC::newArray[4] = {0};
```

In the ABC constructor, I need to overwrite this value with a value constructed at runtime, such as the encoding of an integer:

```
ABC::ABC()
{ 
int i; //some int value defined at runtime
memset(newArray, 0, 4); // not sure if this is necessary
setArray(i,newArray);
} 

...

void setArray(int i, char * value)
{
    // encoding i to set value[0] ... value [3]
}
```

When I return from this function, and print the modified newArray value, it prints out many more characters than the 4 specified in the array declaration.

Any ideas why this is the case.
I just want to set the char array to 4 characters and nothing further.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you printing it? In C++ (and C), strings are terminated with a nul. (`\0`). If you're doing something like:

```
char arr[4] = {'u', 'h', 'o', 'h'};
std::cout << arr;
```

It's going to print "uhoh" along with anything else it runs across until it gets to a `\0`. You might want to do something like:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[i];
```

(Having a `static` tied to instances of a class doesn't really make sense, by the way. Also, you can just do `= {}`, though it's not needed since `static` variables are zero-initialized anyway. Lastly, no it doesn't make sense to `memset` something then rewrite the contents anyway.)

Comment: I think `std::cout << string(arr, 4);` is prettier, instead of the loop.

Comment: @Stephen: Yeah, I just don't like the temporary dynamic allocation. How about a `template <typename T, size_t N> std::ostream& output_array(std::ostream& pStream, T (&pArray)[N], const std::string& pFiller = "") { for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)  pStream << pArray[i] << pFiller; return pStream; }`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, short strings are stack allocated in most string impls.  But, if you're streaming, you're probably not worried about a little extra CPU overhead.  @Ben Voigt's answer looks simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout.write(arr, count_of(arr))
```

If `count_of` isn't defined in a system header:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
inline size_t count_of(T (&array)[N]) { return N; }
```

Comment: what is this `count_of`, of which you speak?

Comment: For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx  If your compiler doesn't provide one, I added a definition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing it using something like

```
printf("%s", newArray); //or:
cout << newArray;
```

? If so, you need to leave space for the nul-terminator at the end of the string. C strings are just arrays of characters, so there's no indication of the length of the string; standard library functions that deal with strings expect them to end in a nul (0) character to mark the ending, so they'll keep reading from memory until they find one. If your string needs to hold 4 characters, it needs to be 5 bytes wide so you can store the `\0` in the fifth byte

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a 5th character with a 0 byte to mark the end of the 4 character string, unless you use custom char-array output methods.  If you set value[3] to something other than 0, you'll start printing bytes next to newArray in the static data area.

There's also no need to explicitly 0 initialize static data.

You can best catch those kinds of errors with valgrind's memcheck tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing out a string that starts at the address &newArray[0] and ends at the first 0 in memory thereafter (called the null terminator).

```
char strArr[] = {"Hello"};
char strArr[] = {'H', 'e', "llo");
char strArr[] = "Hello";
char* strArr = "Hello"; // careful, this is a string literal, you can't mess with it (read-only usually)
```

...are all null terminated because anything in double quotes gets the null terminator tacked on at the end

```
char strArr[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

...is not null terminated, single quotes contain a single character and do not add a null terminator

Here are examples of adding a null terminator...

```
strArr[3] = '\0';
strArr[3] = NULL;
strArr[3] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bit loss of performance, you can fit into 4 byte.. in 'c-style'.
Print either 4 characters or until \0 is reached:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
...
//calculate length
size_t totalLength = sizeof(ABC::newArray) / sizeof(ABC::newArray[0]);
char* arrayEnd     = (char*)memchr(ABC::newArray, '\0', totalLength);
size_t textLength  = arrayEnd != 0 ?
                     arrayEnd-ABC::newArray : totalLength;
//print
fwrite(
       ABC::newArray, //source array
       sizeof(ABC::newArray[0]), //one item's size
       textLength, //item count
       stdout); //destination stream
```

By the way, try to use `std::string` and `std::cout`.